# thrust and auto data transfer

Tags: python, c++, thrust

I got a function in a lib who need to work with data coming from python

First I create a tuple vec3

```
typedef thrust::tuple<double,double,double> vec3;
```

```
void thrust_decimation( double* x, double* y, double* z, long number_of_vertex)
{
    auto data2workwith=thrust::make_tuple(x, y,z);

    std::vector<vec3> local(number_of_vertex); 

        for (int64_t i = 0; i < number_of_vertex; i++)
        {
            local[i]= vec3(x[i],y[i],z[i]);
        }
 
    thrust::device_vector<vec3> keys1 =local;
    thrust::device_vector<vec3> keys2(number_of_vertex);

    thrust::sort(keys1.begin(), keys1.end());
    
    thrust::transform(keys1.begin(), keys1.end(), keys2.begin(), gridTransform(gridscale)); 


    ... work with local
    ... work on x, y, z
    ... return x, y z

}
```

I don't know how to transfer data2workwith. I did a loop but as i got a large amount of data the duration is to long as i need to do it twice.

Comment: I'm confused. You were passed POINTERS to doubles, not doubles. data2workwith is not the same type as vec3. Also what's "thrust"? Is that your code?

Comment: I add a part of the code working with the data @Jellyboy

Comment: @Jellyboy Thrust is a parallel STL replacement with GPU support which is shipped with the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: I would recommend using the `thrust::zip_iterator`, meaning that you do not translate from SoA to AoS, but instead use three `thrust::device_vector<double>` vectors `x_d`, `y_d` and `z_d`, which are then zipped into one iterator which gives these `vec3` tuples when dereferenced. That way you don't have to create a copy in host memory.

Comment: Thanks @PaulG, i will l try this solution.